# How to use selectordie.js jquery plugin with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using [selectordie jquery plugin](http://vst.mn/selectordie/) to style the html select menu. In the same time, I am trying to iterate dropdown options using ng-repeat. But it is not working properly because the plugin replaces select options with spans. And these spans are always infront of the real option values.

Comment: What version of angular and jQuery are you using? From the docs: "Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that."

Comment: I am using jQuery 2.1.3 and angularjs 1.3.8

Comment: Did you find solution @NuttyProgrammer ? I am trying same but not working

Comment: I didn't find the straightforward solution but I solved it by customizing the functionality of selectordie in angularjs. What is your exact requirement? What type of customization do you want?

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer I wanted to build this plugin as Directive with slight variations !